# I have an api key but still get a 401 error

Tags: reactjs, api, environment-variables, netlify

My website won't connect to the OMDB api. It's a React app, deployed through Netlify. When I run the app on local host 3000 it connects no problem. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

This is how I have my api key set up in App.js:

```
searchMovies = async (text) => {
    try {
      const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_MOVIE_KEY;
      const response = await axios.get(
        `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${API_KEY}&`,
        {
          params: { s: text, type: 'movie' },
        }
      );
```

This is what the .env file looks like:

```
REACT_APP_API_MOVIE_KEY=*****
```

This is what the environment variables on Netlify look like:

```
key: API_KEY value: *****
```

And here is the error code I get:

```
Failed to load resource: www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=undefined&&s=kate&type=movie:1 Failed to load 
the server responded with a status of 401 ()
```

Comment: api_key is undefined..Check for the environment variable in netlify

Comment: can you please confirm if REACT_APP_API_MOVIE_KEY is on Netlify as env variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Failed to load resource:
> [www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=undefined&&s=kate&type=movie:1](http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=undefined&&s=kate&type=movie:1) Failed to load
> the server responded with a status of 401 ()

In this error the server is telling you that your api key is undefined. Please log your api key and then check

Answer (score 0):

IMDb ID missing in the url:
example  [http://www.omdbapi.com/?i={imdb](http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=%7Bimdb) id}&apikey={api key}